# C Arguments Not Working?

Tags: c, argument-passing

Why doesn't this work?
When I try to use -l or -s as the first argument, the if statements don't take. They always go to the else statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argv[1] == "-l")
    {
        printf("Yay!\n");
    }
    else if (argv[1] == "-s")
    {
        printf("Nay!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you try to run it, and what happens?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What is the input? What is the output?

Comment: You might already know this, but you should also check if `argc > 1` before you try to use `argv[1]`.

Comment: Most of those `#include`s are unnecessary for this fragment...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot compare strings using `==` operator - use `strcmp()` instead.

By comparing strings using `==` you are comparing the addresses of `char *` pointers, not string values.

Answer (score 4):

In C strings are compares by strcmp function. Instead your compares just pointers. So:

```
if (strcmp(argv[1],"-l") == 0)
{
    printf("Yay!\n");
}
```